# Mongoose-validator: dealing with already hashed password

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have an app that uses passport.js local login and register. Its working fine but I have a problem with server side password validation. The passport.js file generates the password hash before saving the user:

```
  passport.use("local-signup", new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField : "password",
      passReqToCallback: true
    },
  function(req, email, password, done) {

    process.nextTick(function() {

    User.findOne({ "local.email" :  email }, function(err, user) {

        if(err) {
          console.log(err); 
        }

        if(user) {
          return done(null, false, req.flash("signupMessage", "That email is already taken"));
        } else {

          var newUser = new User();


          newUser.local.email = email;

          newUser.local.password = newUser.generateHash(password);


          newUser.personal.firstname = req.body.firstname;
          newUser.personal.lastname = req.body.lastname;

          newUser.save(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                if(err.errors["local.email"]) {

                  return done(null, false, req.flash("signupMessage", err.errors["local.email"].message)); 

                } else if (err.errors["personal.firstname"]) {

                  return done(null, false, req.flash("signupMessage", err.errors["personal.firstname"].message)); 

                } else if (err.errors["personal.lastname"]) {

                  return done(null, false, req.flash("signupMessage", err.errors["personal.lastname"].message)); 

                } else if (err.errors["local.password"]) {

                  return done(null, false, req.flash("signupMessage", err.errors["local.password"].message)); 

                }

            }

          return done(null, newUser);

          });
        }
      });
    });
  }));
```

I need to compare the hashed password with the validator or figure something else. I'm using bcrypt. My user.js model with the validator:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
var validate = require('mongoose-validator');

var nameValidator = [
    validate({
      validator: 'matches',
      arguments: /^[a-zA-Z]{1,30}$/,
      message: 'First and lastname must be between 1 and 30 characters, no special symbols or numbers are allowed.'
  })
];

var emailValidator = [
    validate({
      validator: 'isEmail',
      message: 'Is not a valid email'
  }),
    validate({
      validator: 'isLength',
      arguments: [3, 50],
      message: 'Name should be between {ARGS[0]} and {ARGS[1]} characters.'
  })
];

var passwordValidator = [
    validate({
      validator: 'matches',
      arguments: /^[a-zA-Z\d\W]{8,50}$/,
      message: 'Password should be between 8 and 50 characters.'
  })
];

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  local: {
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique : true, validate: emailValidator },
    password: { type: String, required: true, validate : passwordValidator}
  },
  personal: {
    firstname : { type: String, required: true, validate: nameValidator },
    lastname : { type: String, required: true, validate: nameValidator }
  }
});

userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Comment: Don't validate the password on the server, maybe check the length on the client site